# if raw_input (includes) x, then print y

Tags: python, include, raw-input

```
a = raw_input 'type x here and see what happens'
    if a (INCLUDES) 'x'
        print 'y'
```

What's that `INCLUDES` command? Is there a better way around this?

I am a fan of the web comic Homestuck, in which trolls each have a different way of typing, called quirks. I'm working on a "quirk text" to English translator in Python ([here's](http://www.mspaintadventures.com/?s=6&p=003985) two characters with different quirks I.M.-ing) *I want to make them type like normal humans.*

Comment: Do `if '2' in a` (and couldn't you have just googled something like "python see if string includes other string")?

Comment: dang it, you're right, first link that comes up. Oops, I feel silly.

Comment: fret not, googling is a skill too ;)

Comment: Please don't forget to accept an anwser.

Answer (score 5):

Your code is not valid pythonic. In Python:

```
a = raw_input('type x here and see what happens')

if 'x' in a:
    print 'y'
```

The function `raw_input()` returns a string; the `in` syntax matches 'x' against your string (this is what your **INCLUDE** pseudo-code stands for). If 'x' is found, `print 'y'` is invoked, printing a 'y' on your console.

Comment: ah, I see, but if I type in "excalibur" then it prints y. How do I turn "excalibur" into "eycalibur"

Comment: It prints 'y' because the 'x' matches in 'excalibur', which is expected. I do not understand the second part... if you'd like to match for 'y', just replace the 'x' in the `in` statement. If not, please clarify...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = raw_input()
if "pattern" in a:
    print "match"
```

All the magic is the keyword `in`

Comment: dang, that was fast. Thank you so much!

Comment: I just tried the phrase "I love the pattern on your wall!" on that code, and it responded with "match" how do I get the rest of the sentence in there?

Comment: If you want to "repeat" the sentence, call the a variable in `a` concatenation